# Azure Search to return ONLY record count

Tags: lucene.net, azure-cognitive-search

I have the situation in Azure Search where I need to return ONLY count of matched search results- and not the actual results (will be done separately based on user request). This to reduce payload and hence improve performance.

When I use these parameters to the searchindex
$count=true&search=ruby, 
I get @odata.count": 373 but also get the 373 records

I am able to reduce the records returned by introducing $skip but this is inefficient

Is there a way to **only get result count** and not the actual records

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the query parameter `$top=0`. The docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents).